# getFileById() with dynamic ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

This line of code uses the id entered manually in the script

```
let copyFile =DriveApp.getFileById('1GhpGpHM......').makeCopy(),                    
copyID = copyFile.getId(),                    
copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyID),
```

How could I use the ID that can be found manually written in the google spreadsheet, so that if I change it from the spreadsheet, it will also change automatically in the script. I have a list of IDs associated with some templates.

Can something be done about this?

I used :

```
var ID_template = ss.getRangeByName('ID_template').getValue;
```

and then

```
let copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ID_template).makeCopy(),
copyID = copyFile.getId(),
copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyID),
```

but without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Probably your issue is that you're missing brackets () after .getValue()

Comment: Tank you very much! You are the best!